# (TwitchIO for Python) Invalid syntax error when importing commands

Tags: python, twitch

I'm trying to follow a TwitchIO tutorial in the documentation here: https://twitchio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

I jumped to trying the second block of code which adds an event_message so I copied that code. I just want to run the code so I can begin making a chat bot for twitch. Here is that example code that I copied, the only changes I have made to it have been adding my token and initial_channels (Obviously, not included for privacy):

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise our Bot with our access token, prefix and a list of channels to join on boot...
        # prefix can be a callable, which returns a list of strings or a string...
        # initial_channels can also be a callable which returns a list of strings...
        super().__init__(token='ACCESS_TOKEN', prefix='?', initial_channels=['...'])

    async def event_ready(self):
        # Notify us when everything is ready!
        # We are logged in and ready to chat and use commands...
        print(f'Logged in as | {self.nick}')

    async def event_message(self, message):
        # Messages with echo set to True are messages sent by the bot...
        # For now we just want to ignore them...
        if message.echo:
            return

        # Print the contents of our message to console...
        print(message.content)

        # Since we have commands and are overriding the default `event_message`
        # We must let the bot know we want to handle and invoke our commands...
        await self.handle_commands(message)

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        # Here we have a command hello, we can invoke our command with our prefix and command name
        # e.g ?hello
        # We can also give our commands aliases (different names) to invoke with.

        # Send a hello back!
        # Sending a reply back to the channel is easy... Below is an example.
        await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.name}!')
bot = Bot()
bot.run()
```

When I run this code, I receive this error (Changing user to keep info private lol):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-USER-\eclipse-workspace\TwitchIO\src\botRD.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twitchio.ext import commands
  File "C:\Users\-USER-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twitchio\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Users\-USER-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twitchio\client.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .http import TwitchHTTP
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (await resp.json())
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know where to begin with this issue. I tried going into the twitchio\client.py but it appears to be importing something from .http and I am not sure how to make changes to that or where to go from there. I tried resetting my computer just in case, but that did not fix the error. This is a bit out of my knowledge range, so I would appreciate it if anyone could recommend a good solution. I'm using Eclipse IDE and Windows 10 if that is important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TwitchIO requires python 3.7+ and it looks like you're running 3.6. I suspect this is your problem.

Source: https://twitchio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html